# Symfony 3.3 and tinyMCE. How/where am I supposed to save uploaded images?

Tags: symfony, tinymce

I have developed a Symfony 3.3 bundle, where I use tinyMCE (included its jbimages plugin) to enrich textarea form fields with a RTE. Everything works fine, and a user may upload  images from a textarea field to a folder web/bundles/mybundle/uploads.

Issue is: if it happens I need to use command  `assets:install`, the entire web folder gets overwritten, and I lose the uploaded files. Since it does not seem I may arrange things as to let upload files into a folder outside the web folder, I am stuck.

Is there a way out?
Thanks

Comment: I was wrong. It is easy to let upload files outside the web folder. A fine solution to my issue is, in the file config.php of plugin jbimages, when $config['upload_path'] is defined, use `substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], 0,strrpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/'));` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 2):

You can store somewhere outside of web folder and the create a controller that reads the file and gives a BinayResponse with the requested file. In this way you could even store the files in an external system like Aws S3.

Comment: This is fine, but my issue was even simpler. Thks.